# Why is ln(p_i) not rounded down in theexpression for Shannon entropy?

Tags: entropy

Entropy   supposedly " is the average amount of information contained in each message received"(Wikipedia: Entropy). However, to calculate the Shannon entropy for a finite sample, we have the sum over the of -p_i(log p_i). However, for each i, the amount of information possible  is a positive number of bits, so for one instance one must round down to the nearest integer. Thus I would expect the total sum to be composed of integers; i.e., each term in the sum would be FL(-p_i(log p_i)), where FL is the floor function. Why isn't it?

A similar question then comes up when one considers the properties of the information function I so that I(p)I(q)= I(pq).

Comment: The Shannon entropy of a process/random variable $X$ is the *average number* of bits required to represent $X$. This is the  content of the source coding principle. An average need not be a natural number.

Comment: @Isomorphism:   I don't mean to round off the entire sum nor the parts that calculate the average, but rather to each contribution of bits, which should be integers. If one sample has a probability of p_i = 3/4, then you are not going to get part of a bit of information from it, are you? Perhaps I should have asked whether each term shouldn't be  (-p_i(FL(log p_i))).

Comment: Measuring one sample with p=3/4 won't give you 0.811 bits, but measuring 1000 independent such samples will give you about 811 bits.